# What attack upgrade do StarCraft 2's roaches use?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

The Evolution Chamber allows for 2 different attack upgrades: melee and missile. It's obvious zerglings benefit from the melee upgrade and hydralisks benefit from the missile upgrade, but which do roaches benefit from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roaches benefit from the missile upgrade

source - [sc2 armory: roach](http://sc2armory.com/game/zerg/units/roach)

Comment: Its worth noting, that because of the Roaches' slow attack speed, each upgrade increases Roach damage by +2.  Given their 2 attack time, this is a 1 dps upgrade.  To put this in perspective, the Hydralisk receives 1.1 dps per upgrade.