# What attack upgrade do banelings use?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Seeing [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/what-attack-upgrade-do-starcraft-2s-roaches-use) question reminded me of the only time it wasn't obvious to me which upgrade a certain unit used - the baneling.  Since it is an area attack that is acid, it could have go either way in my head.

Comment: Did you ask this question just to answer it?

Comment: @tzenes To help out the next person who is wondering the same thing.  AFAIK this is kosher on stackexchange sites.

Comment: from pretty much the first section in the stackexchange faq in fact, it says "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on  Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question. "   http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: this is a topic which makes me very uneasy.  I've moved the conversation to meta so this thread doesn't get flooded with comments: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/969/should-we-allow-asking-of-questions-as-a-means-to-provide-answers

Answer (score 11):

[Banelings](http://sc2armory.com/game/zerg/units/baneling) use the Melee upgrade, and gain +2 for each level.

Comment: +4 vs light, and +8 vs buildings.

Comment: It's not a problem that you answer your own question, just give others a shot to answer it before you do it yourself! :-)

Comment: the stackexchange FAQ says this is ok!  I didn't know I'd get so much flack for it, including a downvote!

Comment: The downvote is surely not deserved, like I said it's just more polite to give others a shot first. So don't let it get you down!